# How to do a binding on a property using a custom control?

Tags: xamarin, binding, custom-controls

I create a custom entry, as you can see here :

```
public class ExtendedEntry : Entry
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty BorderColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BorderColor), typeof(Color), typeof(ExtendedEntry), Color.Gray);

    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return (Color) GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I create a custom renderer like this :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace LogiStock.UWP.CustomRenderers
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        ExtendedEntry entry;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            entry = (ExtendedEntry)Element;

            if (Control != null)
            {
                var converter = new ColorConverter();

                Control.BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)converter.Convert(entry.BorderColor, null, null, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used my custom control in a my xaml like this :

```
<controls:ExtendedEntry BorderColor="{Binding ColorError, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Finally, I test in my view model if my entry is empty and I want the color if it is:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Libelle))
{
    ColorError = Color.Red;
}
```

But the borderColor of my control didn't change.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong..

Comment: Two things.
1. Make sure ColorErorr is implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`.
2. In your renderer, you need to override `OnElementPropertyChanged`. That's the method that will fire whenever the BordercColor is changed.

Comment: Thnak's ! That works perfectly !

Comment: Awesome. If you have time, you can answer your own question. This will help other users who may be experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is the answer of my problem :

I override the `OnElementPropertyChanged` in my renderer et I implement the interface `ÌNotifyPropertyChanged` in the class where I declaer my property `ColorError`